# Why does my Whirlpool refrigerator ice maker not make ice exactly one day a week every week?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator, ice-maker

My Whirlpool Gold refrigerator's ice maker does not make ice one day a week. After that day it begins to make ice again as normal. I think I read in the manual about a setting for Jewish households that would halt ice making on the sabbath, but, I can't find it again. I need it to make ice everyday.

Comment: Do you know the model number of the appliance?

Comment: Does it only occur on Friday?  most fridges I know of don't have a setting for date or day of week, rather you just manually turn the setting on Friday before the Sabbath, and manually turn it off after.  during which usually the light either does not operate or is always turned on

Comment: How about consistency? Is it the same time period every week? Do the lights of the fridge stay off at the same time as the ice maker? Does the entire fridge go off, or just the ice maker and/or lights?

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard of this,

Here's what I could dig up:

> Hold down the "Door Alarm" button for three seconds until "F or C" or
>   "On or Off" appears on the display. Many Whirlpool food appliances
>   comply to Jewish religious law by including a "Sabbath" mode, which
>   disables many of the refrigerator's features, including the ice maker.
>   Tap the "Freezer +" or "-" buttons until "SAB" appears on the display.
>   Tap "Refrigerator +" until "Off" appears on the screen. Hold down the
>   "Door Alarm" button for a further three seconds to confirm the new
>   settings.
>
> Read more: How to Fix an Ice Maker on a KitchenAid Refrigerator |
>   eHow.com
>   http://www.ehow.com/how_7954484_fix-ice-maker-kitchenaid-refrigerator.html#ixzz29aiNXHuy